# How to add pool information in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I added a custom agent in the "agent pool" section in Azure DevOps. Under the `details` tab, there's a `pool information` block, which currently says

> No additional information found for pool.

**update**

It's a page on the `Organizational Settings` -> `Agent Pools` -> `Agent` (e.g. Hosted VS2017 page. There it has 3 tabs Agents, Roles & Details. The Details page has an Agent information section that lists what software is on the agent in Hosted Pools. There's a screenshot of it below:

[image: Hosted VS2017]

How can I add some text there?

Comment: What do you mean by "pool section"? Are you talking about an agent pool?

Comment: It's a page on the Organizational Settings->Agent Pools->Agent (e.g. Hosted VS2017 page. There it has 3 tabs Agents, Roles & Details. The Details page has an Agent information section that lists what software is on the agent in Hosted Pools. Personally I've seen nowhere that you can add your own information for custom pools and I can't find any API stuff around this area that you can drive, so I'm not sure its possible.

Comment: @DanielMann yes, I mean agent pool. I updated the question as Colin summed it up quite nicely

Answer (score 0):

I asked Microsoft.
Their comment:

> The pool info has not supported to been defined by yourself. This sounds like a good opportunity for an enhancement. I would request you to post your suggestion in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21, so that others can vote on it and we can prioritize this request better.

Source URL: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/496419/azure-devops-server-2019-trm-no-additional-informa.html

I found somebody else who already suggested this, so I recommend to upvote his feature and hope it will be implemented on short notice.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/444363/agent-pool-information.html